# Can I use exactly-once delivery semantic for mongo source kafka connector?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, mongodb-kafka-connector

I want to know if there is a way to change the default delivery semantic of mongo source kafka connector which by default is At-least once.

I want to use exactly-once delivery semantic.